# Get IP address in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to make a database where I could store people their IP address, so the same IP address couldn't subscribe twice. I already know how to get someone there IP adress but I don't know how to insert it into my database. Here is my code:

```
 // Connect to MySQL
 $mysqli = new mysqli( '***', '***', '***', 'inschrijven' );

// Check our connection
if ( $mysqli->connect_error ) {
die( 'Kan niet verbinden met database. Probeer het later opnieuw. ' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ': ' . $mysqli->connect_error );
}

// Insert our data

$sql = "INSERT INTO inschrijven ( naam, email, aantal,ip) VALUES ( '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['naam'])}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['aantal'])}'";
     // validate agree unless you want to add 'checked' to one of the values

     $insert = $mysqli->query($sql);


 // Print response from MySQL
if ( $insert ) {
echo "U bent succesvol ingeschreven! U heeft bootnummer: {$mysqli->insert_id}. Op de naam: . U krijgt hiervan nog een bevesteging op uw mail, uw bootnummer kan nog veranderen. Hopelijk zien we u op de BotenBouwDag 2016!";
} else {
die("Error: {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}");
}


$mysqli->close();
}

?>


<HTML>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<title>
Welkom op de officiële site van de BotenBouwDag 2016
</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="">
<input name="naam" id="naam" type="text">
<input name="email" id="email" type="email" autocomplete="off">
<input name="aantal" id="aantal" type="number">
<input type="radio" name="eten"> Ja 
<input type="radio" name="eten"> Nee
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Verstuur Informatie">
</form>

<div id="ip"></div>
<div id="address"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
$("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);



document.getElementById('city').value = response.city;
}, "jsonp");
</script>


</body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: You've got the name of the ip address field in your INSERT clause; why don't you have the value in the value part of it?

Comment: Note that storing IP addresses is neither a guarantee (due to dynamic IPs) that a user only can register once, and it might also prevent people who have not registered from registering if they are assigned the IP of someone who has already registered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it right.You shoud add this to the your value part

```
VALUES ( '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['naam'])}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['aantal'])}','{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])}'
```